# Weird 301 redirection by google crawler/facebook share

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some pages on my website www.acethem.com which are having 301 redirection but they are not actually 301 redirects. e.g. www.acethem.com/pastpapers/by-year/2007/ is seen as a 301 redirection to www.acethem.com/pastpapers/by-year by google (I am using "Fetch as google" in webmaster tools.

Now more weird: My paginated pages with page >= 10 are all redirected to homepage:

http://www.acethem.com/pastpapers/o-level/chemistry/page/10/

while

http://www.acethem.com/pastpapers/o-level/chemistry/page/9/ is working properly in google crawler.

Note that all these pages work fine with no redirect in browsers.

Sidenote: on www.acethem.com/pastpapers/by-year/2007/, the facebook share button also points to www.acethem.com/pastpapers/by-year/.

Comment: When I do `curl -vvvv -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)' http://www.acethem.com/pastpapers/by-year/2007/` the response I get is 301 Moved Permanently to http://www.acethem.com/pastpapers/by-year . Could it be that you have logic that depends on User-Agent?

Comment: thx for the reply. How do I check this? there's nothing indicating this in the htaccess..weird thing, when i use screaming frog seo tool on my local machine with a copy of the site, there's no redirect but when i crawl the online site, there is redirect

Comment: Use the curl command I showed you

Comment: thx! it turned out that my host was doing these redirects for bots.